# Calculating large integer constants while retaining precision

Tags: vhdl

I am calculating an integer constant in VHDL that is a product of two large constant numbers (2^17 and 100 million) divided by a generic parameter on the order of 2^19.

To avoid overflow errors, I had to arrange the components so that no interim result exceeded 2^31, but this reduces the precision of the final result by an unacceptable amount (need 22 bits of precision, getting 14). Since the denominator is a generic, I cannot split it into prime factors to keep interim results accurate by doing divides with a large ratio between numerator and denominator.

Is the only way to do this to pull in the math_real package, calculate with reals and cast to an integer?

Note that this is for synthesis, but given that I'm calculating a constant from values that are all known at compile time, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Both integers outside the range –(2 ** 31–1) to 2 ** 31–1 and the use of explicit type conversion to convert floating-point values to integer values are non-portable (potentially between your simulator and synthesis tool). See IEEE Std 1076-2008 Annex D. We tend not to design hardware that operates at frequencies across the entire electromagnetic spectrum or deals with numbers in the range of the number of sub-atomic particles inside the orbit of Jupiter. VHDL can be used in describing the hardware portions of systems gracefully not so much describing how the hardware fits into the universe.

Comment: @user1155120 The purpose of this is to determine a 6.20 bit fixed point representation of the average byte rate per clock in a 100Gbps datapath. Nothing to do with Jupiter or how the hardware fits into the universe. As you can imagine, any reduction in precision will cause the accumulated error (this constant contributes to a value entering an accumulator) to be drastically larger after a few hundred million clocks (or a single second). Can you suggest a way to calculate this constant with 22 bits of precision or more?

Comment: One way is to use `numeric_std`, you can declare signed or unsigned numbers of arbitrary precision to hold your intermediate values. It's a bit of a waste since you're only generating a constant, but it ought to work.

Comment: Besides Brian's method in -2008 you can do the calculation in reals (double precision) and use package fixed_pkg for your 6.20 number and calculations. You could also simply document how to calculate the constant in a comment and provide it as an array of values indexed to represent useful values from your equation. The idea being granularity is related to powers of two and word widths, describing realizable hardware instead of abstract mathematical models.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thanks for mentioning that I could use the numeric_std division operator for arbitrary widths. I forget that numeric_std even has a division operator since it is not useful for synthesis and I typically calculate numeric constants using integers for clarity and speed. It isn't often that my numeric constants exceed 31 bits. I converted my three operands into unsigned and had no issues getting the correct constant value without having to worry about overflowing an interim result. If you submit your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.